# Attempting to make python file executable on mac. Bad interpreter, permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python and I'm attempting to make a python file executable. This is the code

```
#! /Users/<me>/PycharmProjects/untitled3
print ("Hello World")
```

in the terminal I typed.

```
$ chmod +x paperclip.py
```

And then

```
$ ./paperclip.py
```

But I get

```
-bash: ./paperclip.py: /Users/<me>/PycharmProjects/untitled3: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Edit: Even after I changed the top line to

```
#!/Users/<me>/PycharmProjects/untitled3 python
```

or

```
#! /Users/<me>/PycharmProjects/untitled3 python3
```

Never mind. Thanks

Comment: the shebang is wrong. It should mention python. Can you try `#! /usr/bin/env python` instead?

Comment: `#! /usr/bin/env python3` would likely be more appropriate since you're wanting Python 3 instead of the default Python 2. You can create a symlink if it's not already done by following the steps in [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/236394).

Comment: Use `#!/usr/bin/python` to use the OS X system python or a path to the *interpreter* you wish to use -- not the script path